# three.js - add multiple objects (obj & mtl) with a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, three.js

I have a problem in my code and I can't found the mistake(s)... I have a loop which load multiple obj and give them a name but as a result the "objects" array is empty... I would like to give to each object a name in order to detect the intersections (the code is OK for that). It's very tricky because when I click on the different parts of the loaded object (a cathedral), the database is contacted but all the objects have the same name. Do you know why ? Here is the code: objects is the array which stores the all geometries, and object is the argument of the function. load_obj is defined by a loop below (string store in another array: OBJETS which store the name of obj of all parts of the cathedral).

```
for (var i in OBJETS){   
load_obj = OBJETS[i];
loader.load('./Donnees/OBJ/'+load_obj+'.obj','./Donnees/OBJ/'+load_obj+'.mtl', function ( object ) { 
      object.name=load_obj;         
      scene.add( object );      
      objects.push(object);     }, onProgress, onError );       
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I cannot say what is wrong, because it's pretty lack of info, but you can try to debug this code just with use of the `debugger` statement and `console.log` to see what is going on step by step. If you have any questions about how to use these tools, please, fill free to ask here

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that javascript is an asynchronous language.

basically, the load function is called asynchronously, and then the for loop continues executing. So, finally, the for loop stops and the load_obj variable is the name of the last OBJET

[This link](http://www.javascriptcookbook.com/article/Preserving-variables-inside-async-calls-called-in-a-loop) helps to resolve this problem

```
for (var i in OBJETS){ 
    (function(index){
        load_obj = OBJETS[index];
        loader.load( './Donnees/OBJ/' + load_obj + '.obj', './Donnees/OBJ/' + load_obj + '.mtl', function ( object ) { 
            object.name=load_obj;         
            scene.add( object );      
            objects.push(object);     
        }, onProgress, onError ); 
    })(i);
}
```